# Different version of Python. Will Python 3.8.9 work? 3.9?

Tags: python, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the directions for installing ROS 2 it says to install Python 3.8.3. For multiple reasons I can only install 3.8.9. Will this work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381968/different-version-of-python.-will-python-3.8.9-work?-3.9?/) by [jnj](https://answers.ros.org/users/77320/jnj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It might, but it might not, it hasn't been tested and we can't recomend it. We list very specific confirations in [REP 2000](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html) and in the install instructions. If you really can't change your system python try installing ROS in a VM or a container. You'll have a much better user experience, especially if you are new to ROS.

---

Originally posted by [kscottz](https://answers.ros.org/users/13336/kscottz/) with karma: 209 on 2021-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0